# Existence of integer solution of $x^3+y^3+dz^3=0$ with $d$ cube-free

Tags: algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations

I'm reading Cassels' Lectures on Elliptic Curves. I have trouble with Lemma 1, chapter 18:

Let $a,b,c$ distinct integers $>1$ and $d=abc$ cube-free. Let $u,v,w \in \mathbb{Z}$ not all $0$ such that $au^3+bv^3+cw^3=0$. Then there are $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^3+y^3+dz^3=0$.

He defines $\rho$ to be a primitive cubic root of $1$, $\epsilon=au^3+\rho bv^3+\rho^2 cw^3$ and $\eta=au^3+\rho^2 bv^3 +\rho cw^3$ and proves that

$$\epsilon+\eta=3au^3$$
$$\rho \epsilon + \rho^2 \eta=3cw^3$$
$$\rho^2 \epsilon + \rho \eta=3bv^3$$

Multiplying this three values one obtains $\epsilon^3+\eta^3=-d\xi^3$ where $\xi=-3uvw$. So the points $(\epsilon, \rho \eta, \xi)$ and $(\eta, \rho^2 \epsilon, \xi)$ are conjugates over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then he states that the line joining them meets $X^3+Y^3+dZ^3=0$ in a rational point different from $(1,-1,0)$.

I can't understand his last affermation. How can I see that there is another point? Thanks!

Comment: You have two points on the projective curve $C:X^3+Y^3+dZ^3$. Let $L$ join them. Then as $C$ is cubic, $L$ meets $C$ in three points....

Comment: thanks! but how can I exclude the point $(1,-1,0)$?

Comment: Just check your two points and $(1,-1,0)$ are not collinear. That's just showing some 3 by 3 determinant is nonzero.

Comment: I have that the determinant is $\xi(\rho \eta-\rho^2\epsilon+\epsilon-\eta)$ and after some manipulations I have re-written it as $\xi(3au^3+3bv^3+\eta)$. I can't see why this value can't be zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, it suffices to verify that the three points 
$$(\epsilon,\rho\eta,\xi),\qquad(\eta,\rho^2\epsilon,\xi),\qquad(1,-1,0),$$
are not collinear. This can be shown by noting that the determinant
$$\left|\begin{matrix}
\epsilon&\rho\eta&\xi\\
\eta&\rho^2\epsilon&\xi\\
1&-1&0\end{matrix}\right|
=\xi(\rho\eta-\eta+\epsilon-\rho^2\epsilon)=9(\rho-\rho^2)cuvw^4\tag{1},$$
is nonzero; the last equality comes from plugging in the expressions for $\epsilon$, $\eta$ and $\xi$ as follows:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\rho\eta-\eta+\epsilon-\rho^2\epsilon&=&\rho(au^3+\rho^2bv^3+\rho cw^3)-(au^3+\rho^2bv^3+\rho cw^3)\\
&\ &+(au^3+\rho bv^3+\rho^2cw^3)-\rho^2(au^3+\rho bv^3+\rho^2cw^3)\\
&=&(bv^3+au^3\rho+cw^3\rho^2)-(au^3+cw^3\rho+bv^3\rho^2)\\
&\ &+(au^3+bv^3\rho+cw^3\rho^2)-(bv^3+cw^3\rho+au^3\rho^2)\\
&=&(bv^3-au^3+au^3-bv^3)\\
&\ &+(au^3-cw^3+bv^3-cw^3)\rho\\
&\ &+(cw^3-bv^3+cw^3-au^3)\rho^2\\
&=&(au^3-cw^3+bv^3-cw^3)(\rho-\rho^2)\\
&=&(au^3+bv^3+cw^3-3cw^3)(\rho-\rho^2)\\
&=&-3cw^3(\rho-\rho^2).
\end{eqnarray*} 
You already note that $\xi=-3uvw$ and hence identity $(1)$ above follows. By assumption $c\neq0$ and hence the deteriminant is nonzero if and only if $uvw^4\neq0$, i.e. if and only if $u$, $v$ and $w$ are all nonzero.

Suppose toward a contradiction that $uvw=0$; by symmetry, without loss of generality we may assume that $w=0$ and $a>b$. Then $au^3+bv^3=0$ and without loss of generality $u$ and $v$ are coprime; note that $uv\neq0$ because $u$, $v$ and $w$ are not all $0$ by assumption. Then
$$1<\frac ab=-\frac{v^3}{u^3}=\left(-\frac vu\right)^3,$$
which shows that $|v|>1$ and that, contrary to the given assumptions, the integer
$$d=abc=\frac abb^2c=\left(-\frac vu\right)^3b^2c=v^3\left(-\frac{b^2c}{u^3}\right),$$
is not cube-free as it is divisible by $v^3$. We conclude that the determinant is indeed nonzero, and hence that the constructed rational point on the curve $X^3+Y^3+dZ^3=0$ is different from the point $(1,-1,0)$.

Comment: @robbis In reply to your comment on the other answer; we have $|v|>1$ because$$\left(-\frac vu\right)^3=\frac ab>1,$$
which shows that $|v|>|u|\geq1$.

Answer (score 0):

Parametric solution to equation $(x^3+y^3+dz^3=0)$ has been given by Seiji Tomita & is shown below.

$x=p(p^3+2q^3)$

$y=-q(2p^3+q^3)$

$z=-(p^3-q^3)$

$d=(p^3+q^3)$

For $d=9$, the three integral points on the curve $(x^3+y^3+9z^3=0)$ are,

$(x,y,z)=[(20,-17,-7),(2,1,-1),(1,-1,0)]$

The link to his web site is given below. Click on 
computational number theory & click on article #316.

```
         http://www.maroon.dti.ne.jp/fermat
```

Comment: Again, this does not answer the question at all.

Comment: $b\, {{\left( 2 c-b\right) }^{3}}+c\, {{\left( c-2 b\right) }^{3}}=\left( c-b\right) \, {{\left( c+b\right) }^{3}}$